# Not sure why this is happening: Exception thrown at 0x003BADF8 in Monopoly AI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01142018

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to implement reading in a file of a board game.

Now, I know the error is something to do with the first if statement, but as far as I can see, the "index" value should be 2 and thus skipping the if statements altogether.

The next index value is 1, which should hit the if statement, but it keeps erroring out and breaking as it checks the index value, any ideas?

```
class boardSpace
{
public:
    int index, cost, rent, color;
    string street, streetType, jail;
};


void readFile(boardSpace marray[])
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Monopoly.txt");
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
            inFile >> marray[i].index;
            inFile >> marray[i].street;

            if (marray[i].index == 1)
            {               
                inFile >> marray[i].streetType;
                inFile >> marray[i].cost;
                inFile >> marray[i].rent;
                inFile >> marray[i].color;
            }

            if (marray[i].index == 3)
            {
                inFile >> marray[i].streetType;
            }

            if (marray[i].index == 7)
            {
                inFile >> marray[i].street;
                inFile >> marray[i].streetType;
                inFile >> marray[i].jail;
            }

            if (marray[i].index == 8)
            {
                inFile >> marray[i].street;
            }   

            i++;

            if (inFile.eof())
            {
                break;
            }
    }
        inFile.close();
}
```

But keep getting the following error

```
    Exception thrown at 0x003BADF8 in Monopoly AI.exe: 0xC0000005:
 Access violation reading location 0x01142018.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Use a debugger : it will probably show you the exact line where the error happens.

Comment: I have, read the paragraph under the code

Comment: Which statement is at address `0x003BADF8`?

Comment: I recommend using `std::vector` instead of an array.  Easier to pass arrays and `std::vector` can grow dynamically.

Comment: I have to use Array's unfortuantly, not sure what's at that address ( unsure how to find out actually )

Answer (score 1):

The access violation indicates your code is attempting to access memory that it has not allocated. For example, a memory address just beyond the last element in `marray[]`.

would suggest you modify your code to ensure that `i` never exceeds the upper bound of `marray[]`.  If `marray[]` has ten elements, `i` must never be 10 or greater.

You should probably not rely on the file being short enough that it never exceeds the array.

Comment: I've set the array size to be more than what I needed (so I needed 26, so I set the array to be 100) and I still get this error

Comment: In addition to sizing the array, you must also ensure that each element in the array contains a valid pointer to a `boardSpace` instance.